# How can I style my image :hover within a link for a responsive website?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get my `:hover` state to fit the original footer image links.

Here is a photoshopping of the flicker I get on Chrome, on Safari nothing is displayed.

[image: Hover flicker on Chrome]

I'm sorry to link to the actual website but I wasn't able to recreate the problem in a jsfiddle.

Website :

http://couill.art/project/about-duplicate-2 (NSFW)

Code :

```
<div class="row pp-thumbs">

                    <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
                        <a href="http://couill.art/project/about-duplicate" title="About"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb-0-00-36-07.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
                        <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/about-duplicate" title="About">About</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
                        <a href="http://couill.art/project/about-duplicate-2" title="Danger Zone"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-girls-slim-boi-0-00-25-18.png" width="170" height="128"></a>
                        <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/about-duplicate-2" title="Danger Zone">Danger Zone</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
                        <a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate" title="Danger Zone"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-Girls-thumb.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
                        <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate" title="Danger Zone">Danger Zone</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
                        <a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate-2" title="Danger II"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chauve-souris-0-00-02-19.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
                        <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone-duplicate-2" title="Danger II">Danger II</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
                        <a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone" title="About"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb-0-00-36-07.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
                        <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone" title="About">About</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">Animation</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pp-thumb column" data-xl-width="2" data-sm-width="4" data-xs-width="6">
                        <a href="http://couill.art/project/about" title="About"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb-0-00-36-07.png" width="200" height="150"></a>
                        <p class="pp-title"><a data-font="font_dqju2lgtu" href="http://couill.art/project/about" title="About">About</a><span data-font="font_dqju2lgtu">About</span></p>
                    </div>
```

```
.project-panel .pp-thumb img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb img:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;    
    height: auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 170px;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger Zone"]:hover>img {
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-girls-slim-boi.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger II"]:hover>img {
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb.gif) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="About"]:hover>img {
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb.gif) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
.pp-thumbs {
    margin-top: 1.666666666666667rem;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb {
    margin: auto !important;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img>` can't take a background attribute. When you hover over the image, the style change resizes it to zero width and height, because the anchor link surrounding it is an inline element and not block. At that moment, you're no longer hovering over it and the styles snap back.

A combination of techniques got the result you wanted:

```
.project-panel .pp-thumb a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.project-panel .pp-thumb a:hover > img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And move the background hover styles up to the anchor:

```
.project-panel .pp-thumb a[title="Danger Zone"]:hover {
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Thicc-girls-slim-boi.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
/* etc */
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cp37nwx0/

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much, it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score -1):

You could also just use a simple inline JS:

```
<a href="/project/danger-zone"><img title="About" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb-0-00-36-07.png" onmouseover="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/trio-trompettes-rouge-thumb-0-00-36-07.png'" /></a>
```

And notice I'm using relative links instead of absolute links. That might be a better approach.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The question wasn't tagged "Bootstrap" either yet the site uses Bootstrap. The OP asked for a solution to the problem and this solution is perfectly viable. The OP may have simply not known about the possibility of a JS solution, and therefore, didn't tag it as such.